# How to do page grouping in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services

How can I page grouping SSRS after I've create a report? I can do it if creating new report, but do not know how to do it if I already have created reprot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to break groups on page, you right click on the group at the bottom of the report and select "Group Properties".  The second tab on the left in the "Group Properties" is "Page Breaks".  You can select the check box, "Page break options" " "Between each instance of a group".

Then ensure that your headers and your footers you want to repeat with each page are in that group.  If they are not add new headers and footers in the group and remove the old ones.

Answer (score 3):

If by page grouping you mean grouping data in a Data region, such as a Table, then this is how you can do it.

At the bottom of your report is a section showing Row Groups and Column Groups. Click on the Data region, Row Groups will show a line that says "Details". It represents every row in your data set. Suppose my data set has Country and Region columns, I can drag Country into the Row Groups pane. My data rows will be grouped by Country. I can again drag Region and drop it between Country and Details to create a subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

To display a static tablix member (row or column) on multiple pages.

On the design surface, click the row or column handle of the tablix data region to select it. The Grouping pane displays the row and column groups.

On the right side of the Grouping pane, click the down arrow, and then click Advanced Mode. The Row Groups pane displays the hierarchical static and dynamic members for the row groups hierarchy and the Column groups pane shows a similar display for the column groups hierarchy.

Click the static member that corresponds to the static member (row or column) that you want to remain visible while scrolling. The Properties pane displays the Tablix Member properties.

In the Properties pane, set RepeatOnNewPage to True.

Repeat this for as many adjacent members as you want to repeat.