# Is it possible to duplicate a certain page in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a requirement on a report that requires me to replicate a certain page based on a certain data. For example Process page = 5 so therefore the page on which it has the process must be replicated 5 times. Is this possible programmatically on SSRS?

Thanks

Comment: I had a similar requirement and solved it by creating a master report and including the desired page as a sub-report as needed.

Comment: Hi Filburt, How did you replicate it? Mine is based on a data from database that will determine the number of pages for the process page.

Comment: Your  master report just needs a DataSet with the desired number of records. Bind it to a List and it will repeat your sub report the desired number of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Filburt pointed out. You can do this with a subreport.

You need to build a dataset that will contain one row per page to be repeated, so in this case just a list of numbers 1 to 5 will suffice. Then add a table to your report that uses this dataset as it's source. Make the table one column wide and insert your subreport into the only cell. This will produce a 5 row table each of which will contain a copy of your subreport.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I clearly understand it now :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to duplicate the results that needs to be replicated:

[Oracle duplicate row N times where N is a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481112/oracle-duplicate-row-n-times-where-n-is-a-column)

Then you can add page group:

[How to do page grouping in ssrs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698930/how-to-do-page-grouping-in-ssrs)